# Pointer return by a function in C

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, segmentation-fault, return

Following is the code for making a linked list which has 2 pointers. Linked list is getting created (printed) and all pointers (prev + next) are fine. But when I call the function "copay" and assign its value(pointer) to "duplicate", I am getting segmentation fault but if I use only "copay" and don't assign it to any other variable then there is no issue.

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
} node;


void insert(node **head, int data) {
    node *new = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    new->data = data;
    new->next = NULL;
    node *temp = *head;
    if (!(temp)) {
        *head = new;
        new->prev = NULL;
        // printf("\n return  : %d",data);
        return;
    }

    while (temp->next)
        temp = temp->next;

    temp->next = new;
    new->prev = temp;
    // printf("\n return  : %d",data);
}

void print(node **head) {
    node *temp = *head;
    printf("\n");
    while (temp) {
        printf(" %d ->", temp->data);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf(" NULL\n");
}

node *copay(node **head) {
    node *temp = *head;
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    node *head;

    insert(&head, 1);
    insert(&head, 3);
    insert(&head, 5);
    insert(&head, 7);
    insert(&head, 9);
    (head)->prev = (head)->next->next;
    (head)->next->next->prev = (head)->next->next->next->next;
    (head)->next->next->next->next->prev = (head)->next;


    print(&head);
    node *duplicate = copay(&head);

    // print(&duplicate);
}
```

Comment: There is no question here. Looks like some sort of implicit request to debug your program for you. How about you try to do that yourself first, and if you're still unable to find the problem, then post your findings in details. Don't just throw your code at us, this ain't no "Find my bugs for free" service!

Comment: You've not initialized `head` before you pass it to `insert()`.  All bets are off; anything could happen.  You should probably set it to 0 (NULL) before calling `insert` the first time — preferably as an initialization rather than an assignment.

Comment: Jonathan : insert is functioning properly . The only issue is with the last line "duplicate= copay ..." . If i use "copay .. " ,then i am not getting any fault

Comment: The value in `temp`, a copy of `*head`, is indeterminate, because `head` is uninitialized.  You don't know whether the `if` clause will be executed or whether the rest of the function will be executed.  Since you've not shown any address printing, Anuj, I'm not clear how you know that `insert` is functioning properly.  Have you run the code with [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/)?  If not and if it is an option, then you should do so.

Comment: don't cast the return value of `malloc()`, it's harmful. don't call your variable `new`, it's equally harmful (some day someone will try to compile your C code as C++, and it will fail miserably.) don't put excess superfluous parentheses at random places (e. g. `(head)->prev`), it hurts readability a lot.

Comment: ..and learn how to debug.

Comment: In main(), initialize 'head' to NULL at the point of declaration (i.e. node *head;). Else 'if (!(temp))' in your function insert() will behave erratically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very simple problem in function `main()`:

```
node *head;
```

`head` is defined but not initialized.  You must initialize it to `NULL` for `insert()` to function properly, otherwise you have **undefined behaviour**. Incidentally, it is confusing to name `insert` a function that actually *appends* a node to a list. Change this line to:

```
node *head = NULL;
```

I do not understand you you are trying to achieve with these lines:

```
(head)->prev = (head)->next->next;
(head)->next->next->prev = (head)->next->next->next->next;
(head)->next->next->next->next->prev = (head)->next;
```

The rest looks fine to me.

Answer (score -2):

copay() is actually fine while it is running. The problem happens to its caller(here it is main function) after copay() exits. copay() returns a pointer to a node, but the problem is that the local node, temp, is allocated only while copay() is running. When copay() exits, all of its locals are deallocated. So the caller is left with a pointer to a deallocated node.

I would refer you to go through Section 2 of [Pointers and Memory](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/PointersAndMemory.pdf) from Stanford CS Education Library which is on Local Memory.

Source: [Pointers and Memory](http://cslibrary.stanford.edu/102/PointersAndMemory.pdf)

Comment: This is not at all correct.  It is perfectly fine to return the **value** of a local variable from `copay()`

Comment: Actually when I refered the local memory section of the given source it explained with the example that returning pointer to a local variable to the caller function leads to an error since it gets deallocated after termination of the function. It was actually shown in the The Ampersand (&) Bug subsection.
Would you please help me in getting that part clear if I misunderstood it.

Comment: The `copay()` function returns a the value of local pointer `temp`. This pointer does not point to a local variable, it is a copy of the pointer whose address was passed.  From the context, it is either `NULL` or points to an object allocated by `malloc`.  There is a bug in function `main` as `head` is not initialized, but what you are explaining is irrelevant.